# TR Css Class same as TR before it

Tags: html, asp.net, css, html-table

I have a table and I want certain tr to have the same css class as the tr before it.

in the example below the tr with class="?" should have the same class as the ones above.
is this possible?

```
<table>
  <tr class="red">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="?">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blue">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="?">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do table striping?

Comment: @KarlAnderson in a way yes, but not odd even odd. the table might have one time 3 red, 2 blue, and at another time 2 red 6 blue.

Comment: do you want to set this new class dynamically? then you need javascript to do it. If not, the you should do this stuff at server side before giving html to the client.

Comment: What determines the color? You can use that to help determine the logic code that needs to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on Karl idea.

Use Jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/forX/KBfzD/

```
$(function(){
    $(".unknown").each(function()
                       {

                           $(this).removeClass("unknown");
                           $(this).addClass( 
                                           $(this)
                                          .prev()
                                           .attr("class")
                           );
                       });
});
```

I change the ? for unknown. I dont know how to use ? in css/css selector.

Comment: @NicoTek Even I did similar in my jsfiddle which uses "?" as selector using jquery

Answer (score 1):

Every html element is addressable with css, so in the `stylesheet` of your css,if you decalre like `element{

            set the desired property ;
             }`
In this case the element would be **tr** all the table rows will have the properties you have set in above general declaration ,and if you want to override the specific values to some of your `table rows` you can address them like using the **class**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("tr").addClass("red");
    $("tr:nth-child(4n)").removeClass("red").addClass("blue")
        .prev().removeClass("red").addClass("blue");
});
```

This will select every 4th child, remove the red CSS class, add the blue CSS class and the move to the previous element and do the same.

Note: Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qvmf9/50/) that you can play around with.

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure about understanding this problem but:
in css: `tr.classname + tr` gives you the next tr from tr which has a classname. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dejwid/rP2NB/).
You can also checkout [css nth-child,even & odd selectors](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd).

Comment: that's not what he asked @David

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have mentioned, [this is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9Axs/1/). 
It just checks the previous element of class: `?`

Answer (score 0):

without javascript, you can play with element:li:nth-child(x) values
can be anything like n, n+1, 2n+1, etc... and you can give them different values.